# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\secondsite\Scripts\test-query.php

Tags: php

I keep getting this message. I am simply trying to retrieve my table data from a sql db
the line that is giving me the problem is:
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

In the code:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$prodlist = "SELECT item number, item description FROM product";

$result = $conn->query($prodlist);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
//     output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Item Number: " . $row["item number"]. " - Item Description: " . $row["Item      Description"]."<br>";
   }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you actually getting a result back from the query?

Comment: Your query is invalid, `query()` returns `false`, you are trying to use it as an object. Check for errors before using `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

IF you did actually have a table field called item number you would have to quote it so : `item number` with backtick  "`" characters hence you'd have to do the same in your query.